# Simple object detection (python)

Tags: python, algorithm, object-detection

I have an image with a solid background and three types of objects on it. The three objects are of different (but slightly varying sizes) and of different colors.

For example if there is a 40-60 pixel group that is black in color that grouping would be put in group A, if there is a 40-60 pixel group that is white in color that grouping would be put in group B and if there is a 90-110 pixel group that is black in color that grouping would be put in group C. Then the algorithm would need to count the number of objects in each group.

How would I go about creating an algorithm to do this (preferably using python)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answaer to your problem is `Canny edge detector`.

You can find python implementation of it [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_canny.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A way which works is to binarize the image according to the color first.
For example in your case, to detect object A, you make all pixels which are not black white. Then you get an image with only two kinds of colors (black and white). 
And you can use connected component detection to find all the groups of black pixels. If number of pixels in a group is large than 40, you can think it is an object A.
You make want to check out my matlab code [Detect-Gray-Square](https://github.com/pppoe/Detect-Gray-Square)